# i can connect but load time is long

Tags: networking, router, vpn, mtu

I am trying to connect to virtual servers through VPN router(RTX1210) and L3SW(AX3630-s) all settings are the same as previous VPN router(RTX1200) but routers mtu was set at 1280 [Connection timed out]
i changed the mtu of VPN router to 1400 [connection is stable but load time is long and not really usable]

What might be affecting them ?

Comment: Have you done any research? What else have you tried so far?

Comment: Thank you for asking  above question has been resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved:

The RTX1210s Firmware revision was not updated(was stuck at first firmware revision)
After updating the Firmware to the latest one i was able to smoothly integrate the previous settings and was able to have a stable and fast connection.